# WebView2 Is Not Displaying Web Pages

Tags: wpf, xaml, microsoft-edge, webview2

I want to use the WebView2 to (a) display a website, and (b) display a local .pdf file on my WPF app.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/wpf

The Microsoft documentation says I need to download two things on my PC as "prerequisites:"

- Microsoft Edge WebView2
- Microsoft Edge Insider Channels

For the first one I downloaded the "Evergreen Bootstrapper" (not the "Evergreen Standalone Installer" or "Fixed Version").
For the second one I downloaded the "Canary Channel" for Windows 10.

Are these the correct choices?

When I run the code without initialization, the WebView2 control is completely black and does not render the Microsoft website.

```
         xmlns:wv2="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf;assembly=Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf"

        <wv2:WebView2 Name="webView" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Source="https://www.microsoft.com" />
```

Now when I try to call the InitializeAsync() method, it throws an exception:

```
    private async void InitializeWebView2Async()
    {
        try
        {
            await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Exception Message: "{"Unable to load DLL 'WebView2Loader.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"}"

> StackTrace    "   at
> Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2Environment.CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions(String
> browserExecutableFolder, String userDataFolder,
> ICoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions options,
> ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentCompletedHandler
> environment_created_handler)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2Environment.d__3.MoveNext()\r\n
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)\r\n
> at
> Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf.WebView2.<>c__DisplayClass26_0.<g__Init|0>d.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at
> MyProject.MyUserControl.d__3.MoveNext() in
> C:\Projects\MyProject\Views\MyUserControl.xaml.cs:line 58"    string

Thank you.

Comment: Have you installed wv2 as NuGet package for your project?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the prerequisites: The documentation says to install the WebView2 Runtime or a non-stable Edge browser. You don't need to install both. By default WebView2 will use the most stable installed option: WebView2 Runtime, then Edge browser beta channel, then Edge browser dev channel, then Edge browser. canary channel.

Regarding WebView2Loader.dll: WebView2Loader.dll for different CPU architectures is included in the WebView2 nuget package. If you add the WebView2 nuget package as a dependency for your project it should automatically copy the WebView2Loader.dll to the correct location during build. If you are doing something custom, you'll need to ensure you manually copy the correct WebView2Loader.dll files.

Comment: Unfortunately there is a bug, when you use 'AnyCPU'! Microsoft should change the check for 'AnyCPU' to be a 'catchall' (when it can't find the folder that matches the build, always use the 'WebView2Loader.dll' in the root folder.